# Skip the week range from months range in PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I just want to skip the given week from a date range(month range).
For example, I have a date range between **2020-04-01 to 2020-04-30**. I just have to skip the alternate week from this date range which is **2020-04-08 to 2020-04-14 and 2020-04-22 to 2020-04-28**. So my final output will be

```
    [0] => 2020-04-01
    [1] => 2020-04-02
    [2] => 2020-04-03
    [3] => 2020-04-04
    [4] => 2020-04-05
    [5] => 2020-04-06
    [6] => 2020-04-07
    [7] => 2020-04-15
    [8] => 2020-04-16
    [9] => 2020-04-17
    [10] => 2020-04-18
    [11] => 2020-04-19
    [12] => 2020-04-20
    [13] => 2020-04-21
    [14] => 2020-04-29
    [15] => 2020-04-30
```

These skipping should be dynamic like skip every second week, third week and so on...
I hope you understand what I want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

You only need to pass in date for first of month and array of weeks to exclude.

```
function excludeWeeks($dateStart, $excludeWeeks) {
$finalDates = [];
$date = new DateTime($dateStart);    

$daysInMonth = date("t", strtotime($dateStart));;    


$firstOfMonth = strtotime(date("Y-m-01", strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d'))));
    $modifiedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++) {
        if($i > 0) {
          $modifiedDate = $date->modify('+ 1 day')->format('Y-m-d');   
        }
    $weekNumber =  intval(date("W", strtotime($modifiedDate))) - intval(date("W", $firstOfMonth)) + 1;

    if(!in_array($weekNumber, $excludeWeeks)) {
        $finalDates[] = $modifiedDate;
    }
    }
    print_r($finalDates);
}

excludeWeeks('2020-04-1', ["3"]);
```

Will print our:

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-04-01 [1] => 2020-04-02 [2] => 2020-04-03 [3] => 2020-04-04 [4] => 2020-04-05 [5] => 2020-04-06 [6] => 2020-04-07 [7] => 2020-04-08 [8] => 2020-04-09 [9] => 2020-04-10 [10] => 2020-04-11 [11] => 2020-04-12 [12] => 2020-04-20 [13] => 2020-04-21 [14] => 2020-04-22 [15] => 2020-04-23 [16] => 2020-04-24 [17] => 2020-04-25 [18] => 2020-04-26 [19] => 2020-04-27 [20] => 2020-04-28 [21] => 2020-04-29 [22] => 2020-04-30 [23] => 2020-05-01 )
```

Based on your comment, this is what you can do:

```
function excludeWeeks($dateStart, $dateEnd, $excludeWeeks) {
        $totalDays = strtotime($dateEnd) - strtotime($dateStart); 
        $totalDays = round($totalDays / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $finalDates = [];
        $dateStart = new DateTime($dateStart);      

        $modifiedDate = $dateStart->format('Y-m-d');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $totalDays; $i++) {
            if($i > 0) {
              $modifiedDate = $dateStart->modify('+ 1 day')->format('Y-m-d');  
            }

           $weekNumber = (int)$i/7 + 1;

        if(!in_array( (int)$weekNumber, $excludeWeeks)) {
            $finalDates[] = $modifiedDate;
         }
        }
         print("<pre>".print_r($finalDates,true)."</pre>");
    }

    excludeWeeks('2020-04-1','2020-06-18', ["2","4","6","8","10"]);
```

This will exclude all weeks (not accoring to calendar, but as you said, 7 days) and print something like:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 2020-04-01
    [1] => 2020-04-02
    [2] => 2020-04-03
    [3] => 2020-04-04
    [4] => 2020-04-05
    [5] => 2020-04-06
    [6] => 2020-04-07
    [7] => 2020-04-15
    [8] => 2020-04-16
    [9] => 2020-04-17
    [10] => 2020-04-18
    [11] => 2020-04-19
    [12] => 2020-04-20
    [13] => 2020-04-21
    [14] => 2020-04-29
    [15] => 2020-04-30
    [16] => 2020-05-01
    [17] => 2020-05-02
    [18] => 2020-05-03
    [19] => 2020-05-04
    [20] => 2020-05-05
    [21] => 2020-05-13
    [22] => 2020-05-14
    [23] => 2020-05-15
    [24] => 2020-05-16
    [25] => 2020-05-17
    [26] => 2020-05-18
    [27] => 2020-05-19
    [28] => 2020-05-27
    [29] => 2020-05-28
    [30] => 2020-05-29
    [31] => 2020-05-30
    [32] => 2020-05-31
    [33] => 2020-06-01
    [34] => 2020-06-02
    [35] => 2020-06-10
    [36] => 2020-06-11
    [37] => 2020-06-12
    [38] => 2020-06-13
    [39] => 2020-06-14
    [40] => 2020-06-15
    [41] => 2020-06-16
    [42] => 2020-06-17
)
```

You can use whatever startTime and endTime.

Comment: No @JureW I didn't mean that .. I have to skip 2nd, 4th, 6th,8th and so on week in the condition but my date range maybe start from any date and from that date we have to count 7 days for 1 week not according to calendar ...

Comment: Ok, missunderstanding. Will see if I can modify my code.

Comment: Please check now. Should suit your needs.

Comment: great its work I excepted I have modified this according to my need...

Answer (score 0):

The starting parameters are at beggining of code

```
$startData = "2020-04-01";
$endData = "2020-04-30";
$skipData = "2020-04-08"; // skip one week starting from this data
$everyNumberWeeks = 1;

$dateTimestampStartData = strtotime($startData);
$dateTimestampEndData = strtotime($endData);
$dataTimestampSkipData = strtotime($skipData);
$data = $startData;
$dateTimestampData = strtotime($data);
$skiping = 0;$show=true;
while ($dateTimestampData <= $dateTimestampEndData)
{
    $data = date("Y-m-d", $dateTimestampData);
    $dateTimestampData = strtotime($data) + 60*60*24;
    if ($dateTimestampData > $dataTimestampSkipData)
    {
        if (($skiping % (7*$everyNumberWeeks))==0)
        {
            $show = ! $show;
            $skiping = 0;
        }
        $skiping++;
    }
    if ($show)  echo "$data<BR>";
}
```

Comment: Looks good if  I did not change the end date If I am changing my end date it's not working as expected

Comment: I think that you have a starting point to achieve your solution

Comment: No, I have a dynamic date and dynamic skip week date range maybe start from any date and from that date we have to count 7 days for 1 week not according to calendar ...

Comment: These skipping are dynamic like skip every second week ($everyNumberWeeks = 2), third week ($everyNumberWeeks = 3) and so on

Comment: if every week ($everyNumberWeeks = 1) the results are exactly that you mention in your original post